# update carousel items angular/jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, carousel

I have an Angular App with carousel. The carousel is a list that might get updated on events (change order, remove item, add more items on the left/right).

Currently all the plugins I found require me to re-render the carousel upon each list change, and the render is an time expensive action.

Do you know of a good carousel implementation that works well with Angular and easily deals with list modifications?

Thanks!